# sending a file to stdout in C

Tags: c, stdout

I need to write a plain PPM file to the standard output. I have it creating the PPM file and everything, I just cannot figure out how to get it to send it to the standard output.

Any help you can provide is greatly appreciated,

Comment: the `write()` syscall is your friend. stdout is fd 1.

Comment: Is write() POSIX-specific? I'd use fwrite().

Answer (score 2):

you should look up these functions: [open](http://linux.die.net/man/2/open), [read](http://linux.die.net/man/2/read), [write](http://linux.die.net/man/2/write), [close](http://linux.die.net/man/2/close).

then your code will look something like:

```
#include <unistd.h>
int fd = open("/path/to/file", O_RDONLY);
char buf[1024];
int buflen;
while((buflen = read(fd, buf, 1024)) > 0)
{
    write(1, buf, buflen);
}
close(fd);
```

please keep in mind this is untested.

Comment: will this then allow me to pipe the file back into another program?

Comment: I am not 100% positive, but as far I know it should. Just have the next program read from stdin. shouldn't be too hard to find out real quick.

Comment: That `stdout` is wrong: it needs to be either `FILENO_STDOUT` (or `1`) or the function needs to be `fwrite()` and then you need 4 arguments and the file stream is the last argument.  Using `strlen()` assumes the PPM file contains no binary zeroes.  You should probably capture the number of characters from the `read()` and write that many characters with the `write()`.

Comment: @Jonathan, good catches, I've updated the answer with your suggestions.

Comment: You write one character for every 1024 read?  (Think of the priority of assignments versus comparisons.)

Comment: @Jonathan, you are quite right again, took me a second to figure out why what I had was wrong, but now I got it. Updated it.

Comment: sorry this program needs to be written in C ... I just realized the links you gave (@jb) direct me Linux man pages. Sorry for not being clearer

Answer (score -4):

```
fwrite(blah,size_blah,1,stdout);
```

Comment: so would blah be the name of the file?

Comment: No, the name of the buffer containing the data to be written.

Comment: I do not understand..... so lets say the file is new.ppm would blah be "new.ppm"? Also what would size be?

Comment: @belzinga - this is to write data to stdout. If you want to send a file to stdout, see jb's answer.

Comment: @belzinga, or you could just do `cat new.ppm`